# Python pandas how to count rows based on special time scope conditions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
person  action_type        time
A           4           2014-11-10
A           4           2014-11-15
A           3           2014-11-16
A           1           2014-11-18
A           4           2014-11-19
B           4           2014-11-13
B           2           2014-11-15
B           4           2014-11-19
```

So I want to add a new column named 'action_4' which represent the count of  action_type is 4 for the person of the past 7 days(not include itself).
The result like this:

```
person  action_type        time      action_4
A           4           2014-11-10      0
A           4           2014-11-15      1
A           3           2014-11-16      2
A           1           2014-11-18      1
A           4           2014-11-19      1
B           4           2014-11-13      0
B           2           2014-11-15      1
B           4           2014-11-19      1
```

As my the shape of my dataframe is 21649900*3, so avoid using for...in... please.

Comment: why action_4 is 1 for 'A           1           2014-11-18'?

Comment: @Allen as we only calculate the past 7 days, so the value for '2014-11-18' is calculated from ' 2014-11-11' to  ' 2014-11-17', time '2014-11-10' is out of scope.

Comment: The action_type for "2014-11-18" is different in the input and the expected output... I used the one you report in the expected output

Comment: @FLab Oh, sorry my mistake, I just wanna to show that the count for '2014-11-18' should exclude the value of  '2014-11-10'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach.

I think checking an interval based on time (e.g. 7 days) is always very expensive, so it is better to rely on the number of observations. (actually, in latest pandas version they introduced a "time-aware" rolling, but I have no experience with it...)

So my approach is, for each person, to force daily frequency and then simply counting the number of action_4 happened in the last 7 days excluding today. I have added comments to the code that should make it clear, but feel free to ask for more explanation.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

inp_str = u"""
person action_type time
A 4 2014-11-10
A 4 2014-11-15
A 3 2014-11-16
A 1 2014-11-18
A 4 2014-11-19
B 4 2014-11-13
B 2 2014-11-15
B 4 2014-11-19
"""

or_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(inp_str), sep = " ").set_index('time')
or_df.index = pd.to_datetime(or_df.index)

# Find first and last date for each person
min_dates = or_df.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: x.index[0])
max_dates = or_df.groupby('person').apply(lambda x: x.index[-1])

# Resample each person to daily frequency so that 1 obs = 1 day
transf_df = pd.concat([el.reindex(pd.date_range(min_dates[pp], max_dates[pp], freq = 'D')) for pp, el in  or_df.groupby('person')])
# Forward fill person
transf_df.loc[:, 'person'] = transf_df['person'].ffill()
# Set a null value for action_type (possibly integer so you preserve the column type)
transf_df = transf_df.fillna({'action_type' : -1})

# For each person count the number of action 4, exluding today
result = transf_df.groupby('person').transform(lambda x: x.rolling(7, 1).apply(lambda y: len(y[y==4])).shift(1).fillna(0))
result.columns = ['action_4']

# Bring back to original index
pd.concat([transf_df, result], axis = 1).set_index('person', append = True).loc[or_df.set_index('person', append = True).index, :]
```

This gives the expected output:

```
                   action_type  action_4
time       person                       
2014-11-10 A               4.0       0.0
2014-11-15 A               4.0       1.0
2014-11-16 A               3.0       2.0
2014-11-18 A               1.0       1.0
2014-11-19 A               4.0       1.0
2014-11-13 B               4.0       0.0
2014-11-15 B               2.0       1.0
2014-11-19 B               4.0       1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't take into account your action_type column but it can help you to find the correct answer :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(None, columns=["person", "action_type", "time", "action_4"])

df["action_4"] = 0
for index, table in df.groupby('person'):
    table["action_4"] = table.time.apply(lambda x: table[(table.time > (x -
            datetime.timedelta(days=7))) & (table.time < x)].shape[0])
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, table])
```

Comment: Yes, as you say it will works if I don't care about the type of action_type, but as my df has 20million rows so it may cost much time to iterate the dataframe.